# How to run Oracle query with begin/end in SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have created a query block with begin/end and want to run that in SQL*Plus. But how can I run it in the command line?

Actually the code is from some blog and it is used for searching text in the database. ABC is the texts to be searched.

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
declare
TYPE QueryCurType is REF CURSOR;
query1 QueryCurType ;

cursor c1 is select owner,table_name from dba_tables where owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM') and table_name not like '%$%';
cursor c2(t1 varchar2) is select column_name from dba_tab_columns where table_name=t1 and DATA_TYPE in ('NVARCHAR2','VARCHAR2','CHAR');
temp_var varchar2(3000);
query varchar2(3000);

begin
for tab1 in c1 loop
  for col in c2(tab1.table_name) loop
    query:='select '||col.column_name||' from '||tab1.owner||'.'||tab1.table_name||' where '||col.column_name||' like "ABC"';
    --dbms_output.put_line('executing..'||query);
    open query1 for query;
    loop
      fetch query1 into temp_var;
      if concat('a',temp_var) != 'a' then
      dbms_output.put_line('Found String: "'||temp_var||'"# Column:'||col.column_name||'# Table:'||tab1.table_name);
      end if;
      exit when query1%NOTFOUND;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end loop;
end;
```

but this never gets run. How can I run the codes?

Comment: Seeing the entire contents of the anonymous PLSQL block would help, and ORA code(s) if you're getting any.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to follow it with a slash like

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
end;
/
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you Gary.

Comment: question is there is no line displayed in the console. How can I tell sqlplus to print all dbms_output.put_line?

Answer (score 18):

You probably just need a "/" on a line by itself at the end to make it execute.